# R:Color values based on the difference in values between two dataframes

Tags: r

I am currently coloring the table values based on comparison of values in two columns as below. But, i'm unsure how to I change colors if the difference is > 3 (Green), < 3 (red), difference is +/- 3 (blue)

```
mydata<-
School  col1    col2
A   2   10
A   10  7
A   12  31
B   0   3
B   5   2
B   5   1
B   7   7
```

desired output

```
School  col1    col2    col1_color
A   2   10  red
A   10  7   blue
A   12  31  red
B   0   3   blue
B   5   2   green
B   5   1   green
B   7   7   blue
```

My code:

```
improvement_formatter <- formatter("span",
                                   style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x > mydata$col1, "blue", ifelse(x < mydata$col2, "Red","green"))),
                                   x ~ icontext(ifelse(x<0, "arrow-up", "arrow-down"),x)
)
formattable(mydata, list(`mydata$col1` = improvement_formatter))
```

Comment: Why is the second `B` color value `green`? Shouldn't 5 - 2 = 3 or 2 - 5 = -3 result in `blue` (+/- 3)?

Comment: Also why is the last entry "blue" - shouldn't 7 - 7 = 0 be red (< 3)?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with your desired output by comparing the difference of the two columns to the desired color value through ifelse(). I placed the difference in a column to use for the comparison of the none blue output. I created an absolute value column to check for the blue result when entering the ifelse nest.

```
school <- c('A','A','A','B','B','B','B')
col1 <- c(2,10,12,0,5,5,7)
col2 <- c(10,7,31,3,2,1,7)
df111 <- data.frame(school=school,col1=col1,col2=col2)

df111$col1_color <- df111$col1 - df1$col2
df111$col2_color <- abs(df111$col1_color)

df111$col3_color <- ifelse(df111$col2_color == 3,'blue',
                         ifelse(df111$col1_color > 3,'green',
                                ifelse(df111$col1_color < 3,'red','')))
```

Comment: This doesn't match the OP's desired output

Comment: @jpsmith hold please

Comment: No worries I think we either need additional clarification or there was a type-o in the post, just bringing it to your attention!

Comment: @jpsmith i think i may be on target now. Let me know your thoughts.